# Неправильное отображение столбцов

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня каталог книг, на главной странице после начала поиска появляются сами книги, когда книг много, то отображение происходит корректно, но когда остаётся 3-1 книга, то "выдвижное меню" съезжает в лево. Я пытался это исправить, но не получается.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/berlin-sans-fb-demi" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="html/css/style1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="html/css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="had">
        <h1 class="h11">DepositBook</h1>
        <input class="int1" id="searchInput" type="text" placeholder="Что ищите?"> <br>
    </div>

    <div class="menuAA">
        <a onclick="window.location.href='html/5class.html'">5 класс</a> <br>
        <a onclick="window.location.href='html/6class.html'">6 класс</a> <br>
        <a onclick="window.location.href='html/7class.html'">7 класс</a> <br>
        <a onclick="window.location.href='html/8class.html'">8 класс</a> <br>
        <a onclick="window.location.href='html/9class.html'">9 класс</a> <br>
        <a onclick="window.location.href='html/10class.html'">10 класс</a> <br>
        <a onclick="window.location.href='html/11class.html'">11 класс</a>
        <br>
    </div>

    <h1 class="h12">Найденные</h1>

    <div class="booksMenu">
        <ul id="resultsContainer" class="booksConteiner"></ul>
    </div>

    <script src="html/js/search.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css1:

```
.had {
    background-color: #d96653;
}

.int1 {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-right: 280px;
}

.h11 {
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    color: #eee54f;
    font-family: 'Berlin Sans FB Demi';
}

.menuAA {
    background-color: #c45b4a;
    color: white;
    width: 280px;
    height: auto;
}

.h12 {
    text-align: center;
}

.booksConteiner {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 45px;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: var(--spacing-large) auto;
}

.booksMenu {
    
}

.book-element{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px 20px;
}

.book-element__image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 270px;
    object-fit: contain;
}

.book-element__name {
    text-align: center;
}

.book-element__all {
    float: auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
    max-width: 250px;
    margin-top: var(--spasing-medium);
    padding: var(--spacing-small) var(--spasing-medium);
}
```

css2:

```
:root {
    --spacing-small: 10px;
    --spasing-medium: 15px;
    --spacing-large: 30px;
}
```

js:

```
var CLASS5 = [
    {
       "query": "Царевна-Лягушка",
       "athor": "-",
       "pages": "3-4 листа А4",
       "age": "3+",
       "classn": "5 класс",
       "images": "html/js/images/1.jpg",
   },

   {
       "query": "Журавль и цапля",
       "athor": "-",
       "pages": "2-3 листа А4",
       "age": "3+",
       "classn": "5 класс",
       "images": "html/js/images/2.jpg"
   },

   {
       "query": "Солдатская шинель",
       "athor": "-",
       "pages": "4-6 листа А4",
       "age": "3+",
       "classn": "5 класс",
       "images": "html/js/images/3.jpg"
   },

   {
       "query": "Иван - крестьянский сын и чудо - юдо",
       "athor": "-",
       "pages": "3-5 листа А4",
       "age": "3+",
       "classn": "5 класс",
       "images": "html/js/images/4.jpg"
   },

   {
       "query": "Няне",
       "athor": "А.С. Пушкин",
       "pages": ">1 листа А4",
       "age": "3+",
       "classn": "5 класс",
       "images": "html/js/images/5.jpg"
   },

   {
       "query": "Cказка о мертвой царевне и о семи богатырях",
       "athor": "А.С. Пушкин",
       "pages": "8-10 листов А4",
       "age": "3+",
       "classn": "5 класс",
       "images": "html/js/images/6.jpg"
   },

   {
       "query": "Спящая царевна",
       "athor": "В.А. Жуковский",
       "pages": "10-12 листов А4",
       "age": "3+",
       "classn": "5 класс",
       "images": "html/js/images/7.jpg"
   },

   {
       "query": "Кубок",
       "athor": "В.А. Жуковский",
       "pages": "3-4 листа А4",
       "age": "3+",
       "classn": "5 класс",
       "images": "html/js/images/8.jpg"
   },

   {
       "query": "Чёрная курица, или Подземные жители",
       "athor": "Антоний Погорельский",
       "pages": "3-4 листа А4",
       "age": "3+",
       "classn": "5 класс",
       "images": "html/js/images/9.jpg"
   },

   {
       "query": "Заколдованное место",
       "athor": "Н.В. Гоголь",
       "pages": "67-88 листа А4",
       "age": "6+",
       "classn": "5 класс",
       "images": "html/js/images/10.jpg"
   },

   {
       "query": "Муму",
       "athor": "И.С. Тургенев",
       "pages": "12-14 листов А4",
       "age": "6+",
       "classn": "5 класс",
       "images": "html/js/images/11.jpg"
   },

   {
       "query": "Бородино",
       "athor": "М.Ю. Лермонтов",
       "pages": "5-16 листов А4",
       "age": "6+",
       "classn": "5 класс",
       "images": "html/js/images/12.jpg"
   },

   {
       "query": "Кавказкий пленник",
       "athor": "Л.Н. Толстой",
       "pages": "15-25 листов А4",
       "age": "12+",
       "classn": "5 класс",
       "images": "html/js/images/13.jpg"
   },

   {
       "query": "Хирургия",
       "athor": "А.П. Чехов",
       "pages": "3-4 листов А4",
       "age": "6+",
       "classn": "5 класс",
       "images": "html/js/images/14.jpg"
   },

   {
       "query": "Двенадцать месяцев",
       "athor": "С.Я. Маршак",
       "pages": "2-3 листов А4",
       "age": "3+",
       "classn": "5 класс",
       "images": "html/js/images/15.jpg"
   },

   {
       "query": "Робинзон Крузо",
       "athor": "Д. Дефо",
       "pages": "10-12 листов А4",
       "age": "6+",
       "classn": "5 класс",
       "images": "html/js/images/16.jpg"
   },

   {
       "query": "Снежная королева",
       "athor": "Х.К. Андерсен",
       "pages": "13-15 листов А4",
       "age": "3+",
       "classn": "5 класс",
       "images": "html/js/images/17.jpg"
   },

   {
       "query": "О чем говорят цветы",
       "athor": "Ж. Санд",
       "pages": "1-2 листа А4",
       "age": "3+",
       "classn": "5 класс",
       "images": "html/js/images/18.jpg"
   },

   {
       "query": "Приключения Тома Сойера",
       "athor": "М. Твен",
       "pages": "6-8 листов А4",
       "age": "3+",
       "classn": "5 класс",
       "images": "html/js/images/19.jpg"
   }
]

// get DOM elements
const searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput');
const resultsContainer = document.getElementById('resultsContainer');

// search from array
function searchBooks(query) {
    return CLASS5.filter(book => {
        return book.query.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
            || book.athor.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
            || book.pages.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
            || book.age.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
            || book.classn.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
    });
}

// print
function displayResults(results) {
    resultsContainer.innerHTML = '';

    if (results.length === 0) {
        resultsContainer.innerHTML = '<p>Ничего не найдено...</p>';
        return;
    }

    results.forEach(book => {
        const bookCard = document.createElement('div');
        bookCard.innerHTML = `
                <li class="book-element">    
                    <img class="book-element__image" src="${book.images}">
                    <span class="book-element__name">${book.query}</span>

                    <details class="book-element__all"><summary>Подробнее</summary>
                        <option>${book.athor}</option>
                        <option>${book.pages}</option>
                        <option>${book.age}</option>
                        <option>${book.classn}</option>
                    </details>
                </li>
        `;
        resultsContainer.appendChild(bookCard);
    });
}

// handler
searchInput.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
    const query = event.target.value;
    const results = searchBooks(query);
    displayResults(results);
});
```